# How to validate that a "File" field, inside a paragraph, is filled in a drupal form?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, paragraph

I have created a Drupal form with a **Paragraph** in it.

This paragraph contains a **File** field.

I want to **validate** that the user has attached a file.

```
function my_module_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'form_validation';
}
```

```
function form_validation($form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {

    if(!$form_state->getValue('field_qr_dc_spatial_temp_comp')[0]['subform']['field_dc_1_document']['0']['value']){
        $form_state->setErrorByName("field_qr_dc_spatial_temp_comp][0][subform][field_dc_1_document][0",t('Error'));
    }
}
```

field_qr_dc_spatial_temp_comp is the paragraph

field_dc_1_document is the file field

With that code I always get that is not filled.

I have tried to inspect "form_state", but I do not find the document I try to upload.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to check the "fids" field, like this:

```
$form_state->getValue('field_qr_dc_spatial_temp_comp')[0]['subform']['field_dc_1_document']['0']['fids']
```

If there is a file attached, this value will not be empty.

I had tried it before, but debugging with kint, and it seems that kint with async calls (like upload a file) have conflicts, and that field was always empty.